# Notepad++ non-greedy regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-greedy

Does Notepad++ support non-greedy regular expressions?

For example for text:

```
abcxadc
```

I want to get parts using pattern:

```
a.+c
```

And now I get whole string instead of 2 parts. I tried to use the '?' operator but without success.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

### NOTE: This accepted answer is obsolete as of March 31, 2011. Notepad++ v5.9 and higher now support non-greedy regular expressions.

### Please see an updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971052/notepad-non-greedy-regular-expressions#answer-11864379) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18415890/62536).

---

Notepad++ doesn't support the lazy `?` modifier. Instead, you can specify what you *don't* want:

```
a[^c]+c
```

Which specifies: *match `a`, followed by one or more character that isn't `c`, followed by `c`*. This will match `abc` and `adc`.

Comment: Duh. Genius. Haven't thought of that before.

Comment: **UPDATE**  Non-greedy regular expressions are supported in version 5.9 (version 5.9 (build time Mar, 31. 2011) and later. H/T to @UGEEN answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415871/how-can-i-do-a-non-greedy-regex-query-in-notepad/18415890

Answer (score 69):

I did the following with Notepad++ V6.1.5 (It has now PCRE regex engine):

> a.+?c

and got 2 parts (`abc` and `adc`)

Lazy(non-greedy) searches are now possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415871/how-can-i-do-a-non-greedy-regex-query-in-notepad/18415890

Answer (score 65):

Update: 
*from version 5.9 (build time Mar, 31. 2011), Notepad++ supports non greedy regular expressions (new scintilla 2.5).*

Answer (score 1):

While cleaning up a logfile of dispensable parts, I had trouble using non-greedy regular expression with "Replace All" and an empty "Replace with" pattern.
My solution was to make the pattern match the whole line without changing the rest of the line.

Example: remove every start of line up to the first semicolon: instead of `^.+?:` ->   now use `^.+?:(.*)$` -> `\1` and press "Replace All"

Comment: Thanks. I had to resort to the same method.