# Regular expression to select from X to Y

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I have the folowing HTML:

```
<Some Html above....../>
<!--Template Start -->
<div>
<p>Some text</p>
...
<div>
<!--Template End -->
<Some Html below/>
```

Now how can I write regular expression to match all text from **Template Start**  to
**Template End**

here it says that notepad++  use Scintilla engine.
[Notepad++ non-greedy regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971052/notepad-non-greedy-regular-expressions/5753921#5753921)

Comment: Do you mean `<!--Template Start -->((.|\n)*)<!--Template End -->`

Answer (score 9):

```
<!--Template Start -->(.*?)<!--Template End -->
```

**s** modifier should be switched on.

Comment: @Howard actually 4 seconds :)

Comment: how to switch s modifier, I am new to regular expression.

Comment: @user637307 What programming language do you use?

Comment: I am using Notepad++ text editor, which is written I think in Visual C++(with Microsoft Visual Studio)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there are no nested templates:

```
<!--Template Start -->(.*?)<!--Template End -->
```

Note to switch on mode DOT_ALL to also cover newlines.

Comment: how to switch on mode DOT_ALL, because I am new to regular expression.

Comment: @user637307 Which language do you use?

Comment: I am using Notepad++ text editor, which is written I think in Visual C++(with Microsoft Visual Studio)

Comment: I don't know which kind of regular expressions Notepad++ supports. You can also try `((.|\n)*?)` instead of `(.*?)`.

Comment: here it says it use Scintilla engine.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971052/notepad-non-greedy-regular-expressions/5753921#5753921

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame, but Notepad++ doesn't support matching newlines (\r\n) natively in regex mode. It does support matching newlines only in extended mode.
However it DOES support INSERTING newlines in both modes.

To achieve desired results, you can do a workaround:

1. Delete all newlines in extended mode (replace `\r\n` with nothing) so you have one-liner.
2. Do regex manipulations in regex mode.
3. Add newlines back in extended mode (e.g. replace `<div>` with `<div>\r\n` and so on) or regex mode.

I've read somewhere that PythonScript plugin for N++ adds better support for regexes but  I haven't checked it.