# Notepad++ regular expression replacement

Tags: regex, notepad++

Hello i have here a big file and i need to replace some values so i have to use regular expression:
can anyone help me and tell how to do that?

```
<FieldRef ID="{FE652450-8A96-416E-AAE4-F85BE196A249}" Name="CG"  DisplayName="CG"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{AAA6ABCD-CE07-4D0E-A689-773DD47F4D64}" Name="Statut"  DisplayName="Statut"/>
  <FieldRef ID="{F13A3B87-47DE-4DE2-B480-FE1126B0D5E2}" Name="ElementCMin"  DisplayName="Element C Min"/>
```

So in this lines i need to replace ID="{guid}" by empty string.

Comment: ID="[^"]+" should do it.  Untested though, and don't remember the particulars with Notepad++'s regex flavor.

Comment: Just a tip: before replacing anything you can use the Notepad++ "Mark" function to check if your replacing is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following

```
ID="{[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}"
```

Comment: You could also be more specific, replacing the '+' with the exact count of characters:
ID="{[a-zA-Z0-9-]{36}}"

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do

```
ID="\{.*\}"
```

Do a replace with empty following line and you are done.
However, if you have more occurrences of something ending in `}"`, notepad will do the wrong thing, applying the replace function on this line

```
text1 ID="{F13A3B87-47DE-4DE2-B480-FE1126B0D5E2}" 
text ID="{F13A3B87-47DE-4DE2-B480-FE1126B0D5E2}" text2
```

will remove everything except

```
text1 text2
```

however look at [Notepad++ non-greedy regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971052/notepad-non-greedy-regular-expressions) if you need to resolve this problem.

EDIT:
If you have notepad++ version 5.9 or more the corret regex is

```
ID="\{.*?\}"
```

It stops at the first curly brace in the row

Comment: @Benoit it seems that you didn't even read my whole answer, the problem was already pointed out before my first edit. Assuming the file is all like the example my answer works fine. Assuming the file has multiple guids in a single line, using np++ v 5.9, the edited answer works fine.